# The size of my table is bigger than my screen

Tags: php, css, mysql, sql, html-table

I have a .php file where I show data from a database, but the size of my table is bigger than my screen...

I modified the size but it still seems wrong, it still looks bigger:

This is the image:

[image]

As you can see the scroll bar exceeds the display..

This is my code:

```
  <table width="100" height="100" border="1">
<tr height="50">
<td>Número</td>
<td>Id Producto</td>
<td># Parte</td>
<td width="80">Descripci&oacute;n</td>
<td>Cantidad</td>
<td>Precio</td>
<td>Subtotal</td>
<td>Descuento</td>
<td>total</td>
</tr>
<?php 
include('conexion.php');
$con = conexion();
$sql="select  * from prec pre, prodc pro where pre.idpr=pro.id ";
$res=mysql_query($sql,$con);

$contador=1;
while ($dato=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$contador."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$dato['idproducto']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$dato['parte']."</td>";
    echo "<td width='20'>".$dato['descripcion']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$dato['cantidad']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$dato['precio']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$dato['subtotal']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$dato['descuento']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$dato['total']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $contador++;
}
?>

</table>
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: What is the problem? And what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to adjunt my table on my screen... My table looks so big

Comment: so put sizes on ALL of your cells. you put widths on ONE, so the browser is free to grow the rest as big as it wants. Or put a width limit on the table itself.

Comment: Btw, this `select  * from prec pre, prodc pro` that should throw you an error. `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`

Comment: @MarcB I did it but the table still look big

Comment: did u try <table style="width: 80%" border="1">?

Comment: The problem is not with your HTML, it's with your SQL, just as I already stated. [15 minutes prior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765981/the-size-of-my-table-is-bigger-than-my-screen#comment42112969_26765981) to this comment, but you didn't bother responding. Look at the image you posted, look at the codes in the cell. This entire line `select  * from prec pre, prodc pro where pre.idpr=pro.id` **is wrong** and for so many reasons. It's going to be very hard giving you a definite answer, without knowing your DB schema.

Comment: Anyway now you know. Good luck with that and tell everyone else who have given you answers to either delete them, or adjust accordingly.

Comment: @ALL answers below - So far, all of those given so far are incorrect. It's SQL not HTML.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an HTML5 doctype your width attribute will not work. You will have to use CSS.

```
<table style="width:100%; height:100%; border: 1px solid black;">
```

However, if you need it exactly 100%, you will need to remove the padding/margin from the body and html element.

```
<style>
body, html{ width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
</style>
```

even still, it will be 1 pixel too large because of your 1px border.

---

**Edit:**

As Fred tried pointing out several times, you got some funky SQL going on there as well:

```
select * from prec pre, prodc pro where pre.idpr=pro.id
```

Should probably be something like:

```
select * from pre, pro where pre.idpr = pro.id
```

or

```
select * from prec AS pre, prodc AS pro where pre.idpr = pro.id
```

depending on what your intentions were.

Comment: Explicitly setting column widths using CSS will help as well. Otherwise the columns can stretch.

Comment: @Tim unless you have a good idea of how large each col should be better just let the browser figure out the col sizes IMO

Comment: Right, but the screen shot shows a really wide column that's pushing content off the edge of the screen. If it needs to be that wide it's OK, but if he can cut that back a little it may help.

Comment: @Tim if you take a peek at the code he posted, the really wide col is the one he expressly set the width of. if he let the browser do it it wouldn't be that wide :p

Comment: @Adelphia [**Here's your big chance at solving this...**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765981/the-size-of-my-table-is-bigger-than-my-screen#comment42113463_26765981) - wink. I'm surprised nobody else but me caught that, but OP doesn't want to listen to me. Maybe the OP will listen to you lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- yea, i missed that, but if that's the issue he wouldn't be getting any results and then wouldn't have a table at all.. correct?

Comment: @Adelphia That's just it, the OP isn't getting any results. Look at the image the OP posted and zoom in http://i.stack.imgur.com/6hAtQ.png - Notice the `"Puerta` and `//Here I have etc.` inside the affected cell. That's why and isn't populating correctly, which is why the cell is so wide like that. I know I'm right about this.

Comment: You're a smarter man than me Fred, why don't you ever post answers?

Comment: +1 Finally, someone who listened to me lol and no, I did not want to post an answer for this one, fearing it would open up a big can of worms lol. @Adelphia

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
<table width="100" height="100" border="1">
```

To

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use scroll, use overflow: scroll

If you want to make the table smaller, use css to change the width of either the individual cells or the whole table.

If neither of those are your cup of tea, you may need to split the table into two table, and stack ontop of each other.

Is the table going to have more data than what you currently show in the image, because that's important to finding the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code reduced the width of the table to the minimum needed to keep the words from breaking:

```
<table height="100" border="1">
 <tr height="50">
  <td>Número</td>
  ...
 </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a jsfiddle of it:  http://jsfiddle.net/briggs_w/oym1x8mh/